# Having trouble in routing ( giving urls or path) in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, object, url, view

This is my main project urls . Now I have an app which is routed by path('', include('mysite.urls')),. Now I have a folder named crmAPi for creating apis. This api folder is not an app though, just a folder. I route the urls by using path('api', include("mysite.crmapi.urls")),.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('mysite.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api', include("mysite.crmapi.urls")),

]
```

Now, this is my crmApi urls. The problem is I can access to first path, i can see airilnes list. No, matter what i do, i cannot acces flightdetails. What is the problem with the route?? help pleaseee?? even i create a different listview, again I cannot the route, only the arilines one, I can access.

```
urlpatterns = [

        path('', views.AirlinesListAPIView.as_view(), name='api'),
        path('api/flightdetails', views.FlightDetailsListAPIView.as_view(), name='flightdetails'),

]
```

This is my view.

```
class AirlinesListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    # permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    serializer_class = AirlinesListSerailizer
    queryset = Airlines.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)



class FlightDetailsListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    # permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    serializer_class = FlightDetailsListSerailizer
    queryset = FlightDetails.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)
```

Comment: Are you accessing the flightdetails view under `http://127.0.0.1/api/flightdetails`?

Comment: I think duplication of `api` in the path is a problem here. flightdetails are accessible on `/apiapi/flightdetails`

Comment: Yes, i just posted an answer with that assumption as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you included the `api.urls` under `api/` path. And inside `api.urls` you also have `api/flightdetails`, which contains `api`.

My assumption is that you're trying to access `http://127.0.0.1/api/flightdetails`, but it doesn't actually exist, because `FlightDetailsListAPIView` is accessible under `http://127.0.0.1/api/api/flightdetails`.

If you want access it via `http://127.0.0.1/api/flightdetails`, you should rename the path to:

```py
path('flightdetails/', views.FlightDetailsListAPIView.as_view(), name='flightdetails'),
```